# Solving a three variable exponential equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have the following function:
$$
y=a.x^b+c
$$

And I have a finite set of already calculated values for the `x` and the `y`. Using this data set I need to calculate the values of `a`, `b`, and `c`. Is there a way to do so?

I didn't manage to get an answer using what I remembered from solving multivariable equation since I can not simplify the equation based on `b`.

**Additional information about the specific use case:**

- In the data set, the value of `x` is in the range [0-256] inclusive
  and the value of `y` is in the range [0-65535] inclusive and both are natural numbers. However not all values are necessarily available. For example the set might start at `10` and continues to `250`.
- `a`, `b`, and `c` are decimal numbers with `b` always being bigger than `0`.
- The set contains around 256 pairs of `(x, y)` essentially
  resulting in around 256 equations that can be used to solve this. $[(x_1,y_1)-(x_{256},y_{256})]$

Comment: For $x = 0$, $c = y$. Now choose two pairs of $x, y$ values and you have two simultaneous equations to solve.

Comment: @an4s, Unfortunately I might not have a value for `y` when `x` is zero. I have added this to the question. The range might start at `10` and ends with `250` as an example. Sorry that I didn't mention this in the question in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for any $i,j,k,l$,
   $$ \dfrac{y_i - y_j}{y_k - y_l} = \frac{x_i^b - x_j^b}{x_k^b - x_l^b} $$
In principle this allows $b$ to be determined, but in most cases this can only be done
numerically.  However, if you're doing it numerically in any case, you might as well
use a numerical algorithm for a [nonlinear least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-linear_least_squares) fit on the whole dataset.

If there are $i,j,k,l$ such that $x_i/x_k = x_j/x_l \ne 1$ (call this common ratio $t$), then you can simplify the above equation to $$ \dfrac{y_i - y_j}{y_k - y_l} = t^b$$
so that $b = \log_t((y_i - y_j)/(y_k - y_l))$.  Then knowing $b$ you have
$a = (y_i - y_j)/(x_i^b - x_j^b)$ and $c = y_i - a x_i^b$.

Comment: So for $i = 20$, $j = 60$, $k = 10$, $l = 30$,

$b = log_2(\dfrac{y_{20} - y_{60}}{y_{10} - y_{30}})$

?

Comment: Tested and worked perfectly. I just need to be careful about choosing the 4 points for calculation. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I don't think that there is an analytical solution to your problem.

In the first place, it will have no solution if you have more than three points and they don't exactly belong to the curve. You have two options - pick three reliable points or - use a best fit method.

In the first case, rewrite the equation as

$$\log(y-c)-(b\log x+\log a)=0.$$

Then assuming a value of $c$, use two points and solve for $\log a,b$ (this is a $2\times2$ linear system).

$$\begin{cases}b\log x_0+\log a=\log(y_0-c),\\b\log x_1+\log a=\log(y_1-c).\end{cases}$$

And a third point gives you a value of

$$f(c):=\log(y_2-c)-(b\log x_2+\log a)$$ which will in general not be zero. In fact, this scheme defines a function of $c$, of which you can find the root(s) by a standard numerical algorithm.

---

If you prefer the second option, for a value of $c$ you can compute a least-squares line fit on $\log a,b$, and from this compute the total error

$$\sum f^2(c).$$

Now you will solve with a numerical minimization algorithm.